# Angularjs formly nested form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I'm very new to angular - please be patient :)
I would like to have a nested form - something like:

```
name:{
 firstname:"",
 lastname:"",
}
```

This is my "formly" function:

```
this.getFormFields = function (categories) {
     var meta={
        metadata:{
          title:"hello",
          description:"test123",
        }
     }
     return [{
        key: 'name',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
          label: gettextCatalog.getString('Name'),
          required: true
        }
      }, 
      {
          key: 'metadata',
          type: 'input',
          model:meta.metadata,
          templateOptions: {
            label: "metadata title",
           }
       },
      {
        key: 'clientId',
        type: 'input',
        templateOptions: {
        required:true,
        label: "clientId"
         }
       },
      }];
    };
```

So how to add nested fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in luck! This was just made insanely easy in angular-formly's 7.0.0 release (which was pushed out yesterday). Here's [an example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/advanced/nested-property-keys).

For your specific case, you'd probably do something like:

```
{
  key: 'name.firstname',
  type: 'input',
  templateOptions:  {
    label: 'First Name'
  }
}
```

Comment: ahhh - awesome thats great. Problem is i'm using loopback angular-admin. But this is my problem then :) so i need to update it. Great thank you!

Comment: is it possible to make key name something like this `key: name[0].firstname` ?